# Applying HMTL attributes in HTML Helpers in MVC

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem that how to apply HTML attributes in HTML helpers like TextBoxFor.
here is a sample code

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FullName, htmlAttributes: new { @class="form-control",@id="fullName"})
```

for ID and class, it works fine but when I add the required attribute or read-only, it shows an error.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FullName, htmlAttributes: new { @class="form-control",@id="fullName", required})
```

In the above line when I added the required attribute, it displayed this error:

> The name 'required' does not exist in the current context

Comment: I tried this. It removed the error but it is generating html tag like this <input type="text" required="required" />

Answer (score 0):

Add required attribute to your model like this:

```
 [Required]
 public string FullName{ get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this way.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FullName, htmlAttributes: new { @class="form-control",@id="fullName",  @required = "required" })
```

Comment: same output like <input type="text" required="required" />